# Withdraw my published paper from open access journal

Tags: journals, open-access, disreputable-publishers, withdraw

Because the journal is not recognized by UGC. Kindly please suggest how to withdraw my paper in an open access journal.

Comment: Has the paper been published by the journal or has it been accepted for publication but not yet published?

Comment: You might want to expand "UGC" in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Your paper is published. That means the publication process is over and it's too late to withdraw it.

Besides, since your paper has been published, even if you could withdraw it, it can no longer be published anywhere else (at least without violating most journals' stated policies on novelty).